Using Random Forest with Multiple Observations per Participant
I've collected data where each participant provided ratings (1-5) for 12 different items, and I want to use Random Forest Regression for prediction (predicting ratings for a new participant). I'd appreciate your insights on the following:

Does potential dependency between observations pose a problem for Random Forest? I'm asking because the bootstrap process likely includes repeated samples within trees – does this not partially address the dependency issue?
If dependency is problematic, what is the best approach?


Splitting train/test sets by participants, so that all 12 ratings from a participant stay within the same set?
Using hierarchical models (mixed models)?
Other solutions?
I've already run the model (sklearn Random Forest Regression) without accounting for dependency and am happy with the performance, but I want to ensure I'm not overlooking any issues.

Thanks!

If you are scoring your models on a test set that was split without regard to the participant, then it won't (likely) be an unbiased estimate of future performance. You don't necessarily need to accommodate the dependence in the model itself, but the test set needs to be looking at fresh participants if that's how you'll use it in production.
(As a thought experiment, maybe the (tree-based) model learns only the average rating each participant gives, using an accidental participant_id column that was included in the training set. That model will just predict a constant rating equal to that of the last training participant when put into production. On a test set of new larger ids, you'll recognize that; but on a random set of rows including some whose participants also appeared in the training set, performance may look pretty good.)
